# Can I disable global/general chat?

Tags: overwatch

I have literally no use for the global chat feature, as I am either going to play solo, or with my friends. All that I get from global chat is random people saying random things, so can I just disable it?

Note: This is not the same thing as "All chat" or "team chat" in matches. This is the global (probably regional or server based) chat that you are in between matches (in the lobby).

Answer (score 7):

You can remove yourself from the channel typing `/leavechannel general` in the chat. If you are talking in general channel, you can just type `/leavechannel`

Right now, however, as soon as you restart Overwatch and sometimes when you leave a match you will rejoin the General chat channel automatically and will need to leave again.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** remove yourself from the default global chat that you are put in while in the menus.

However, you can take yourself out the in-game chat channels by going to the Groups tab under the Social menu by hitting escape while in a game.

Comment: is this for "all chat/match chat" or "global chat" which is the chat you are in if you are not in a match?

Comment: Ahh I thought in-game global chat was what you were asking about. In that case no there's no option I'm aware of but I don't see it being used too often.

Comment: @Dragonrage On the Xbox, it looks like the only chat you can be in between games is Team chat. In games you have Team and Match. Is there some other additional chat you're referring to?

Comment: @DCShannon on the pc there is a "global chat" that you get dumped in when you aren't in game.

Comment: @Dragonrage That's odd. Who's even in that? I mean, if you're not in a match, then the only people you're associated with are on your team. Who else would you be chatting with?

Comment: @DCShannon random peeps who are the same global chat. I suppose global may be a misnomer, as it is more likely regional or server based. I can take a picture to show what I mean when I get home.

Comment: Blizzard has a similar type of global chat in Heroes of the Swarm which is far as I know, anyone that is in the HoTS menu, not currently in a game. Which is the same thing in Overwatch. It's something Blizzard likes to do for some reason. My guess would be to give players a simple way to find others who might want to group up for a game.